# Is it possible to set the cache size for fuse and/or sshfs?

Tags: linux, filesystems, distributed-filesystems, sshfs, fuse

I can't seem to find something in the documentations. Is it possible to set the cache size for fuse and/or sshfs and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, sshfs caches things for 20 seconds, use -o cache_timeout=N to change the default cache timeout (in seconds) or -o cache=no for disabling the cache.

You can also control cache timeouts for directory listing etc with -o cache_stat_timeout=N, -o cache_dir_timout=N, and -o cache_link_timout=N.

---

also u can use system-wide cache

-o kernel_cache

Comment: shfsmount user@host /mnt/shfs -o cachesize=256 does not work with sshfs :) It's for shfs not for sshfs.

Comment: sorry) so u have use kernel cache and system-wide settings or use timeouts.

Comment: maybe u can use FS-Cache / CacheFS over sshfs  to do cache &turn off sshfs cache.sorry, not tried that. see this article http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/CacheFS